Recover or add a default directory
Thanks Alot for the help in advance
I'm using Azure Portal for the first time and have deleted my default directory. Now im trying to figure out to recover it or add new and set it as default. I have searched alot im not getting a correct way or procedure to do the same. And hence I now feel that it might not be possible to do so
Please help if you know the solution to this issue is.
Thanks Again

what you see when you select your email address from the top-right of the page.
and click on Switch directory?
Do you get to select a tenant from the All Directories section? If you don't see All Directories section, you don't have access to multiple tenants.

I see “All Directory” and there is a default directory of my organization. Previously I had both mine and organizations directory visible there and I deleted mine by miskate as both were labelled as default directory

If you have deleted your default directory in Azure, it may not be possible to recover it. You have to probably raise a ticket with MS. If it exists, or you want to switch to another one then select your email address from the top-right of the page.  Select Switch directory.

Select a tenant from the All-Directories section. If you don't see All Directories section, you don't have access to multiple tenants or as you said got deleted. Doesn't exists anymore.

In that case you will have to create a new directory, follow the steps in this  Microsoft document.
To set the new directory as default, follow the steps in this  Microsoft document.
Similar MS Case

I see you have added a Contoso directory, can you guide me through I'm struggling to get an Azure student account

Please refer to Creating Azure for Students Account for creating a student account. Check the presequisites from here- What is Azure for Students? Resolve student sign-in problems
